# Converting &amp; to & in the url of jsp

Tags: javascript

From the db i am getting the value and passing as the url for my jsp. It contains of 2 variables.

```
Select * from table where name='"+name+"' &class='"+class';
```

But in my url instead of `&` , `&amp;` is coming.

Comment: Just change it to `&amp;`.

Comment: but  the page is not rendering when iput &amp; only with & its working

Comment: Then change it to `&amp;amp;`

Comment: Try changing `&` to `%26` possibly?

Comment: Thanks @KrisHollenbeck it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use URL encoding.

Try changing `&` to `%26`

**Some info on URL encoding**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp